# Starting a VPC EC2 instance via PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've been searching a lot for AWS SDK examples and tutorials and I finally found the official documentation on [Starting an Amazon EC2 Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSdkDocsPHP/latest/DeveloperGuide/how-to-ec2.html) but the issue is that is doesn't describe how to launch an EC2 instance in a VPC; additionally how does one create a VPC in PHP. I have had many issues with the AWS SDKs due to poor documentation, as a side question if anyone could point me to a .Net and/or PHP AWS SDK tutorial that covers many topics I would really appreciate it.

Update
I've finally got a chance to test the link above and it works great for EC2 and so I started looking at the file `./aws/services/ec2.class.php` and it has a function with the signature  of `run_instances($image_id, $min_count, $max_count, $opt = null)` In the array `$opt` you specify the settings that your instance will be created with, I found that there is an optional array within `$opt` that is `NetworkInterface` which has an option for `SubnetId`. This suggests that this is where the magic is; I have tried using these options but the instance fails to start. Hope these details help and thanks again for your time.